# Is it possible to use amazon cognito to authenticate a Private API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I need to develop a private API Gateway at the company where I work.

What left me in doubt is that when using amazon cognito's OAUTH2.0, it generates a URL for authentication.

But I didn't find anything on the web talking about such an authentication for a Private API.
This url for authentication of amazon cognito will always be exposed on the internet? Can I develop a Private API with a cognito private authentication url?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a private api with public authentication, but there is no concept of private authentication with the Cognito User Pools hosted UI.  End users will be able to authenticate, but not call your api unless they are in the VPC.  This [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/protect-public-clients-for-amazon-cognito-by-using-an-amazon-cloudfront-proxy/) describes an approach if you don't use the hosted UI.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Thanks